# Ethernet connection USB 3.0

Tags: ethernet, thinkpad

i've got a thinkpad X1 carbon gen 2 with thinkpad onelink pro dock. the usb and HDMI port work well but the ethernet port does not.

I found a driver here : https://www.asix.com.tw/download.php?sub=searchresult (third line)

but i'm stuck for the install : when i tried to "make" the files, it's says "error 2" (see picture)

can you help me to install it or find an other solution...

Thx

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367838/compiling-error-while-installing-realtek-rtl8111e-in-64-bit-13-10-config-x86-x Check this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one shouldn't have spaces in the folder names (containing the driver of course) when building the driver. Replacing the spaces with underscores should fix the issue.